# Ubuntu 19.10 cannot detect networked or WiFi printers

Tags: printing, 19.10

I have a Canon iP110 printer that is visible to my laptop running Windows 10 as both a Wifi printer and a network shared printer. This printer is not detected at all by Ubuntu 19.10 running on the same laptop. How can I get Ubuntu to detect this printer?

Comment: Did you try to add a network printer?

Comment: Yes. That why I am asking this question. The settings app will not detect the printer, therefore I cannot add it.

Comment: Try to manually add the printer IP.

Comment: Okay. Shall I then assume auto-detection of printers not physically attached to the laptop is broken?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not using 19.10.